# Objective C float is not showing all decimals

Tags: objective-c, floating-point, double, nsnumber

I'm passing a float to a method but it's not showing all decimals. I have no idea why this is happening.

Here's an example:

```
[[LocationApiCliente sharedInstance] nearPlacesUsingLatitude:-58.3645248331830402 andLongitude:-34.6030467894227982];
```

Then:

```
- (BOOL)nearPlacesUsingLatitude:(double)latitude andLongitude:(double) longitude {



    NSString *urlWithCoords = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@&lat=%f&long=%f", CountriesPath, latitude, longitude];
```

Printing urlWithCoords will result in:

format=json&lat=-58.364525&long=-34.603047

More of this. What I'm getting from the output terminal:

```
(lldb) p -3.13419834918349f
(float) $4 = -3.1342
(lldb) p -3.13419834918349
(double) $5 = -3.1342
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Change the `%f`s in your formatting strings to specify the desired number of decimals, e.g., `%.16f`.

Note that the number of decimals shown does not guarantee that they are *correct*, but at least they won't be truncated.

Overall the problem is that floating point numbers do not contain information about the precision, and cannot precisely represent some decimal values, so formatting can not in the general case “autodetect” the number of decimals. So you just need to override the default by specifying the desired number and accept that it's not representative of location accuracy. But since you seem to be passing the floats to another program via the URL, this shouldn't be a problem—a larger number of decimals is better.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like CoreLocation uses doubles to represent degrees, so I'd be surprised if there's any more geographic precision to be found on the device.

But, in general, if you want to represent higher precision than double, you can use `long double` in Objective-C like this...

```
long double myPi = 3.141592653589793;
NSLog(@"%16.16Lf", myPi);
```